# how do I make the click of any picturebox within a class call a subprocedure

Tags: vb.net

I'm making monopoly and I've made a class with all the information about each tile (picturebox, name, owner, price...)
how do I get a subroutine so that if I click on any tile, it will bring up a menu asking whether to buy/sell houses and stuff
The main thing I need to know is how to make it happen under any property clicked and how to tell which particular one was clicked without the need for lots of code
Note: I'm new to windows forms (2 days), so I may not understand advanced stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a click event in the tile class. Internally this click event would be raised by the picturebox' click event handler. The main program can register an event handler for all tiles' click event:

```
Class Tile
    'Define the signature of the event
    Public Delegate Sub TileClickHandler(sender As Tile)

    'The UI control of this tile
    Dim Container As PictureBox

    'The event is raised whenever the tile is clicked
    Public Event Click As TileClickHandler

    Public Sub New()
        'Register a private event handler for the UI control's click event
        AddHandler Container.Click, AddressOf Container_Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub Container_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'The UI control has been clicked, raise my own Click event
        RaiseEvent Click(Me)
    End Sub
End Class


'Main Program
Dim tiles = New List(Of Tile)
'...
For Each t In tiles
    AddHandler t.Click, AddressOf TileClicked
Next

Private Sub TileClicked(sender As Tile)
    MessageBox.Show("Tile " & sender.ToString() & " has been clicked.")
End Sub
```